# Retrieving ActiveX classID from the system registry with C++

Tags: c++, flash, qt, activex, registry

I am working on a windows  application that has a shockwave flash player embedded in it.The C++ part should be able to call Flash movie methods and vice versa.Initial experiment was done using MFC.It works.But now I want to port it to Qt as it allows easier UI development.Qt has got QAxObject which holds the ActiveX control you assign to it via setCotrol() method which should get a classID of the ActiveX or its name.Because the classID is more reliable than a name and because I have not found an example where flash player ActiveX is accessed using a name ,now I want to know how to retrieve that classID from the system registry of the OS.I suppose that for every machine some specific activeX classID may vary (correct me if I am wrong on it) .If it is true then I need to access the registry ,find shockwave activeX classid and then pass it into QaxObject::setControl() method.How do I do that?

Forgot to mention that in MFC application the ActiveX control gets the requested ActiveX automatically once you select the ActiveX type from the list of available system controls.In Qt you have no such an option.

---

Reading this http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/acm.html   I understand that the CLASSID is constant on any machine.Is it true ? If yes then please discard my question as there is no reason searching for the ActiveX key on specific machine by the ProgID if it is the same always.
Thanks.

Comment: If you lookup the control name in the registry to find the CLSID, you are doing the same thing as creating the control by name, only with a lot more effort.

Comment: What you are saying is fine but I need a practical example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to query from the registry by mime type. You can find details on where that is stored here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751976%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can look up the mimetype in the registry and get the CLSID from that. You can look it up by name as well; the locations of both registry keys are explained in that document.

Comment: There are no examples there on how to implement it in C++